# How to access the key and value associated with that key in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have data such as

```js
const data = { 
  "map":{ 
     "2019-12-27T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "11:00-11:15"
     ],
     "2019-12-29T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "10:00-10:15"
     ],
     "2019-12-26T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "10:00-10:15",
        "10:15-10:30",
        "11:00-11:15",
        "11:15-11:30",
        "10:00-10:15",
        "12:00-12:15"
     ]
  }
}
```

How can I access the key and value associated with that key? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get enumerable keys of the object:

```js
const data = { 
    "map":{ 
       "2019-12-27T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
          "11:00-11:15"
       ],
       "2019-12-29T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
          "10:00-10:15"
       ],
       "2019-12-26T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
          "10:00-10:15",
          "10:15-10:30",
          "11:00-11:15",
          "11:15-11:30",
          "10:00-10:15",
          "12:00-12:15"
       ]
    }
  }

  const keys = Object.keys(data);    //gives you array of keys
  console.log(data[keys[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
let singlestamp = data.map["2019-12-27T18:30:00.000+0000"]
```

In JavaScript you can use dots or you can put the key in quotes in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` to go over key and values of any object.

```js
const data = {
  map: {
    "2019-12-27T18:30:00.000+0000": ["11:00-11:15"],
    "2019-12-29T18:30:00.000+0000": ["10:00-10:15"],
    "2019-12-26T18:30:00.000+0000": [
      "10:00-10:15",
      "10:15-10:30",
      "11:00-11:15",
      "11:15-11:30",
      "10:00-10:15",
      "12:00-12:15"
    ]
  }
};

Object.entries(data.map).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log({ key, value }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `for-in` loop in JS

```
const data = { 
  "map":{ 
     "2019-12-27T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "11:00-11:15"
     ],
     "2019-12-29T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "10:00-10:15"
     ],
     "2019-12-26T18:30:00.000+0000":[ 
        "10:00-10:15",
        "10:15-10:30",
        "11:00-11:15",
        "11:15-11:30",
        "10:00-10:15",
        "12:00-12:15"
     ]
  }
}

for (const property in data.map) {
  console.log(`key - ${property} value - ${data.map[property]}`);
}
```